# image not displaying for checkbox (css)

Tags: html, css, image, checkbox

I'm trying to use images as checkboxes in a grid layout, but the images won't show and I'm at a loss. Here is the relevant css and html. I have double checked the image address as this has been an issue in many other posts here, but it is stored at the address being accessed.
Any help is appreciated.

```css
body{
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
.jumbotron {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}
.four {
 width: 32vw;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
 /*background-color: #95a5a6;*/
} 
.row {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 20vh;
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
.buttonLabel {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.button input[type="checkbox"] {
 display: none;
}
.button input[type="checkbox"] + label {
 width: 32vw;
 height: 20vh;
 display: inline-block;
}
#accomLabel {
 background: url('../img/shelter.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row jumbotron heading">
      <h1 style="text-align: center;">foo</h1>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">bar</h3>
    </div>
      <form method="post" id="services_form">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="four">
              <div class="button">
                <input type="checkbox" id="accomButton"></input>
                <label class="buttonLabel" for="accomButton" id="accomLabel"></label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="four">
              <div class="button">
                <input type="checkbox" id="foodButton"></input>
                <label class="buttonLabel" for="foodButton" id="foodLabel"></label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="four">
              <div class="button">
                <input type="checkbox" id="medicalButton">                 </input>
                <label class="buttonLabel" for="medicalButton" id="medicalLabel"></label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine, although you don't need input closing tags (`</input>`). Here's a demo with placehold.it image:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.four {
  width: 32vw;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  /*background-color: #95a5a6;*/
}
.row {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.buttonLabel {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.button input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  width: 32vw;
  height: 20vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
#accomLabel {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/54x54') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row jumbotron heading">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">foo</h1>
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">bar</h3>
  </div>
  <form method="post" id="services_form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four">
        <div class="button">
          <input type="checkbox" id="accomButton">
          <label class="buttonLabel" for="accomButton" id="accomLabel"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four">
        <div class="button">
          <input type="checkbox" id="foodButton">
          <label class="buttonLabel" for="foodButton" id="foodLabel"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four">
        <div class="button">
          <input type="checkbox" id="medicalButton">
          <label class="buttonLabel" for="medicalButton" id="medicalLabel"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Syden, I have removed the closing input tags as you said. The placeholder.it image works perfectly, however the png i have saved locally still doesn't appear.
Edit: It turns out the image is too large, thanks for the help :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad you could find the root of the issue :) Regards.